# Nest.js disabling cors for a route not working/ or then not working for any route anymore

Tags: nestjs

I want to disable cors checks for my healthcheck and struggle to get this done.

My app is created as this in bootstrapping:

```
const server: express.Application = express();
   server.use(compression());// enables gzip encoding

   const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, new ExpressAdapter(server), {
      logger: logger
   });
   app.enableCors();
```

where logger is a winston logger (has been wirking before i tried indroducing a health chekcing- so is not the problem source)

my AppModule goes like this

```
@Module({
    /* stuff that is uncahgned to working version before ... */
})
export class AppModule {
   configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
      console.log('yes executed app confogure')
      consumer
         .apply(cors({
            origin: (requestOrigin: string, callback: (err: Error, origin?: boolean) => void) => {
               console.log("Exec check");
               callback(null, true);
            }
         }))
         .exclude({ path: '/api/health', method: RequestMethod.GET });
   }
   ...
```

I can also see that "yes exeuctes app confogure" is in my log so the configure method seems to have been execued. However in case of a request I cannot see the statement "Exec check" in my log so all requests pass without cors validation...

Similarly if i put the main cors configuration into main.ts setup then it's always applied - also for my health check.

Ideas?

Cheers,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to specify the other routes this should act upon.

```js
@Module({
    /* stuff that is uncahgned to working version before ... */
})
export class AppModule {
   configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
      console.log('yes executed app confogure')
      consumer
         .apply(cors({
            origin: (requestOrigin: string, callback: (err: Error, origin?: boolean) => void) => {
               console.log("Exec check");
               callback(null, true);
            }
         }))
         .exclude({ path: '/api/health', method: RequestMethod.GET })
         .forRoutes('*'); // use .forRoutes('(.*)') if fastify
   }
   ...
```

And your middleware should be attached again